# How do I pass a 3dMax mesh from a maxscript funtion a C# function?

Tags: c#, maxscript, method-signature

I have a mesh that's created in a maxscript script.
And I want to pass it to my C# code, I just can't get the right function signature apparently...
It works with a void function (code is called, I get a breakpoint, string is passed back to 3dMax)

I load my DLL, create my object, and try to pass the mesh to the function, but I get the following error:

> > MAXScript MacroScript Error Exception:
> >     -- Runtime error: No method found which matched argument list <<

My maxscript code that loads the DLL:

```
newMesh = mesh vertices:verts faces:faces   

dotnet.loadassembly ( dllDir )

ThisTestObject  = dotnetobject "_3dMaxExporter.Test" "test"

myText = ThisTestObject.TestFunc newMesh
```

C# code:

```
    public string TestFunc(Autodesk.Max.IMesh test)
    {
       return ("You can call me " + Name + "!");
    }
```

Any idea what type i need to have in my signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `UIntPtr` or `IntPtr`. `UIntPtr` if you want to pass it via handle (`getHandleByAnim` MAXScript side, `GetAnimByHandle(UIntPtr handle)` .NET side), IntPtr if you want to pass it via its address (`refs.getAddr` MAXScript side, `MarshalNativeToManaged` method of `Wrappers.CustomMarshalerMesh` .NET side).